# Access an Collection within a form via VBA out of a Class-module

Tags: vba, forms, class, collections

I just like to reorder the VBA of a bunch of Forms in Access, doing all nearly the same. So I created a class clsPopup and I just want to pass some collections out of all this Forms into the class, so I can access their entries over there or in there or how ever.

I could pass the Form-element of the Popup to the class as I created a sub named `Load` in clsPopup like

```
Dim m_frm As Form  

sub Load(frm As Form)
    Set m_frm = frm
    debug.print m_frm.colSp("Name")
end sub
```

In the Form I tried

```
Dim m_clsPopup As clsPopup
Dim colSp As Collection

sub Form_Load()
    Set m_clsPopup = New clsPopup
    Set colSp = New Collection

    colSp.Add "SomeString", "Name"
    m_clsPopup.Load Me.Form

end sub
```

At this point I got the 2465 Runtime error in the line of `m_clsPopup.Load Me.Form`.

My main idea is, to just collect all the needed data within the Forms as collections and than I easily could work with them in the class.

Of course I thought of arrays, but collections seems so much more handy and I could avoid some terrible indexing.

Ahh, and it needs to work in Access 2010. Might that be the problem?

I feel like just a tiny pice of code is missing. Could anyone help to create nice code out of a masterpiece of redundancy?

Comment: Error 91 isn't "missing object or can't access it", error 91 is "Object variable or With block variable not set", and what this means is that you haven't `Set` the object variable. `m_frm` is an *object variable*, so the `Set` keyword is **required** to assign it. The `Load` procedure needs to do `Set m_frm = frm`.

Comment: Then, if the signature for `Load` is `Load(OneSingleParameter)`, then you get error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" with `clsPopup.Load arg1, arg2`, because `clsPopup.Load` has one parameter and you're passing two. That said I would **strongly** advise against naming an object variable the same name as its type/class.

Comment: @Mat's Mug Thx for these two comments, I fixed the first issue and refreshed the question.

Comment: @Mat's Mug and you are right, I shoud have mentioned, that indee I changed the Load-Function, as it now can get two input variable: `Public Sub Load(frm As Form, colSp as Collection)`, but still I get the error 5, as if the collection is not acceped as a valid input. How ever, I even checked `Public Sub Load(frm As Form, colSp as Variant)` with m_clsPopup(Me.Form, colSP), still error 5.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please keep in mind that readers can't see your screen. You need to [edit] your post and clarify what the specific issue is, and provide a [mcve] that reproduces that problem.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: Ok, I tried again to focus on the main point. I removed some blabla and now you can find a Minimal example, that work, or better, that trhows the error 2465 in my case.